# CSS absolute block pseudo element that inherits width

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar with some keywords and on-hover these keywords should display a dropdown megamenu. The keyword and the dropdown menu are both children of the same `<li></li>` element. The problem is that I have space between this keyword and the dropdown menu, so you can't hover over the keyword and drag your mouse to the megamenu without it disappearing.

html snippet:

```html
<li>
    <Link to="/my_link">keyword</Link>
    <div>Menu</div>
</li>
```

To solve this I tried to use the ::after pseudo-element like this:

```css
li a::after {
  content: "";
  /* display: block; */
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #56FD65; /* just to show */
}
```

**This (pseudo-)element would need to be positioned absolute, but once I do that I cannot find a way to make it inherit the width from it's parent. The width of the parent is set to auto.**

The elements have a varying width. Just trying to make the keyword elements big enough so there is no gap will make me need to completely redo part of the navbar.

Comment: Give either the `li` or the `a` element `position: relative`, and then just use `left:0; right: 0;` on the pseudo element.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand, but this worked.